How to modify the position in which one column of an Excel chart is positioned above another?
I must deliver a report for my company and they ask me to change the "plane" in which the columns are displayed. That is, according to the screenshot of the graph that I share with you, the navy (dark blue) column is the one that should "stand out" and be positioned ahead of the gray column:

Even though I tried to change the order of the data, the second column always presents a "higher hierarchy" over the first column. That is, the order in which the data is consulted does not matter. As an example in the following screenshot I will modify the order by placing the WEB VISIT 2024 data first, but as we see, now the WEB VISIT 2023 column is the one that takes the relevance:

That is why when modifying the column overlap value, the right column usually "steps on" the left column.

It doesn't matter if the data for the graph comes from different sheets for each year, or if the same table stores the data for both 2023 and 2024 together. The problem is generated from the graph.
I have already studied the option of using another type of graph, however, I wanted to consult with people who are experts on the subject or request help to find out if it is a mistake on my part. I thank you in advance for your support.
I will be very attentive to your comments and ready to carry out tests.
Excel Version: (Microsoft® Excel® para Microsoft 365 MSO (versión 2403 compilación 16.0.17425.20176) de 64 bits)
I want the navy column to have a higher hierarchy and be ahead of the gray column. Not like it is now where the gray column is the one that rests in front of the navy column


I think it is not possible to interchange which bar is in front. 1st series will always be at the back and higher series in front.

What you want can be achieved with helper columns where you can check which value is smaller and then arrange so that it becomes series one. Your chart will be based on the helper columns. Having said that, compare only the first value in the range. You can’t compare all values else you will not get the correct chart.

This is how Excel charts work. The first series is drawn under the second, and the second under the third, etc. Overlapping columns in a chart like you are doing is really not a great idea, because it interferes with how human cognition judges values in the chart. The partially occluded column looks smaller, even if it is actually taller.
